# If you accelerate and decelerate, is there energy loss?

Tags: acceleration

When you accelerate something, it takes energy. That is the same when you decelerate it. Does this result it net energy loss if you accelerate something then decelerate it?

EDIT: To clarify, I am meaning actively inputting thrust (e.g a rocket engine) not passive drag and friction. Or suppose we have two equal thrusters on opposite sides of the ship (that way it's going nowhere).

A couple of people have noticed the exhaust, but wouldn't that only account for half the energy?

Comment: Calculating energy loss requires that you define the size/content of your system. Does the system include the fuel and exhaust of the rockets or only the mass of the "something" being accelerated. And ultimately, there is no net universal energy loss, only transfer of energy in or out of a system.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context of "energy loss" and what you consider to be your system.

For example, if you accelerate something in air and then stop applying force, it should decelerate due to the air drag.  The same thing happens on a surface with friction.

That energy doesn't disappear, but it is lost to the air/surfaces in a way that would be difficult to recover again as kinetic energy.

If you were to decelerate the object using a system that recovered 100% of the energy, you could speed it back up again to the same speed.  In reality this would not be perfectly achievable.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the kinetic energy of any object using $KE=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$.  If you accelerate an object, and then decelerate it back down to exactly the same speed, then its kinetic energy is the same before and afterwards.  Thus, there is no net energy loss or gain.

Comment: But it takes energy to do so!

Comment: It takes *exactly* the amount of energy you reclaim from the system through the deceleration.  Of course, if you decelerate using something like friction, which prevents you from reclaiming all that energy, then we'd say there was a net energy loss because you put energy into it to accelerate and then failed to reclaim that energy as you decelerated.

Answer (score 0):

The body is not losing energy through deceleration, the energy is "dissipating " on forces such as drag, friction etc. Total, net energy stays the same.

Considering your edit:
I also think that by energy you mean force and are mistaking one for the other. To stop the body you need force to act in opposite direction of movement, not energy.
 The thrust used to stop the body will use the same amount of "energy" (force) the body already had in the beggining. Thrusters "gain" their "energy" (force) through chemical reactions.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you've used two lots of chemical energy for nothing?

Comment: @Mathmagician Well, it's not for nothing, you want to stop the body, don't you?

Comment: @Mathmagician You've traveled somewhere and controlled the movement.  It's not for nothing.

Comment: As in, the energy for two different locations is the same, right? Anyway, we can have it that it uses another two burns to get back to the original position. Then you've traveled nowhere. Or suppose you have two oppsoite thrusters so it stays in the same place. Is this an entropy increase?

Comment: @Mathmagician The body is going nowhere and you have increasing pressure on the body.

Comment: @Mathmagician You're still spending the chemical energy to spew the propellant in both directions, along with as Plexus said, putting more pressure on the body.

Answer (score 0):

To accelerate an object, say, you need to bring in an external force upon it. This will speed up the object and hence it has aquired extra energy. NOW to decelerate it you have to bring in an external force in the opposite direction. The object now slows down and looses the extra energy that the object was given. The accelerating forces may be obvious such as a push, throw, engine, etc. Decelerating agents are generally subtle like friction of various types, gravity, electromagnetics, etc.